# Ng-include doesnt work in Sails Js

Tags: sails.js, angularjs-ng-include

I have a problem with ng-include.
in my Layout.ejs I have de html ng-app
This is my code:
homepage.ejs:

```
<div class="slide">
        <div class="container" ng-controller="slide">
            <h1 class ="main-title"> equipo mate </h1>
            <ng-include src ="'partial.html"></ng-include>
        </div>
    </div>
```

angular.js:

```
 angular.module('app',[])
    .controller('slide', function($scope){
    });
```

and partial.html, that have "HEllo World"

This is the error: angular.js:12410GET http://localhost:1337/partial.html 404 (Not Found)

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is client side framework.

```
<ng-include src ="'partial.html"></ng-include>
```

Which means, this line is executed in your browser
and Angular tries to get http://localhost:1337/partial.html to include it in view.

Now you have to ensure that partial.html is available at that (or some public path).

You **should put** `partial.html` **inside assets folder** for this.

EJS is rendered on server side (in this case).
Angular is rendered on client side.
You should have clarity on this when using both together.